# Is there a name/pattern for a container that holds business entities?

Tags: python, design-patterns, architecture

I find myself often implementing a class that acts as a glorified container for my business entities. Usually i just suffix that class with "model", which is very undescriptive and broad.

An example (python):

```
class MyBusinessEntity:
    pass

class MyBusinessEntityModel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.entities = []

    def create_entity(self):
        self.entities.append(MyBusinessEntity())

    # Implement the rest of the CRUD operations
```

This class will act as my main data repository and will most likely use some kind of data access object for persistant storage.

Does this kind of class have a name? I came across the [Repository Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html), but i don't know if that's really the thing i am looking for.

Comment: This is a broken down version of what i run in my program. Usually there will be multiple lists of different entities and some kind of persistant storage mechanism behind it.

Comment: What's the goal? Having a list with less functionality? Could this be a kind of facade pattern? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern

Comment: @timgeb I want to have more of a central data repository that the rest of the application can talk to without having to know, how or if the data is saved. The list could also be a couple of lists, dicts and sets, or more elaborated data structures like trees etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are correct, this is basically an in-memory implementation of the [Repository Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html).** Typically, application services (where your use cases are implemented) would use it to retrieve business objects and do something with them.

### Types of repositories

The two main flavors of repositories are **collection style repositories** and **command style repositories**. The former try to simulate in-memory collections as closely as possible, whereas the latter has a command-based interface. The main difference is with updating: The command style repository has an explicit `update` method.

### Usage

Let's stick with the command style repository for this example. With such an example, read use cases usually look like this (pseudo-code):

```
books = bookRepository.findByAuthor(theAuthor)
ui.show(books)
```

a create call could look like

```
book = new Book(author, isbn, ...)
bookRepository.create(book)
```

an update call could look like

```
book = bookRepository.getById(bookId)
book.Author = newAuthor
bookRepository.update(book)
```

### Notes regarding your implementation

One thing that is a bit strange with your code sample is that your repository instantiates the business object by itself. **This is not the responsibility of a repository.**

Rather, an application service would create one, and pass it to the repository in a `create` call. Consequently, `create` on a repository usually doesn't mean "create the business object", but "add this object here to the data store". In case of an in-memory repository, this would just mean adding the object to an internal collection.

Comment: What is an example of a application service? In a MVC scenario, would that mean, that i create the business object based off user input in the controller and then just register it at the repository? Same with updating, do i update the object itself and just inform the repository that it was updated?

Comment: In an MVC scenario, the application service would be the controller. Regarding your other questions, I updated the answer.

Comment: Awesome, that is far more simple than i imagined it to be. Thank you for the elaborated answer!